# How to ignore a ROW in Average function, set up by a Max function?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, max

I will try my best to explain my dilemma; in Column B23:B37 is a list of numbers from which I would like to get the Average (`Function - =AVERAGE(B23:B37)`).
The problem is, the biggest number (B30 = 8.3) should not be counted in the Average function.

My solution to this, is `=ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGE(IF(B23:B37<>MAX(B23:B37);B23:B37)))`
And the result you can see in the image = 1.73

The thing is, as you can see in de Column A (same list of number, just without the 8.3 number) equals 2.22 . I guess, that the real average, without the B30 Row.

My formula must be all wrong! how can I make this work?

[image: Hier das Google sheet BILD]

Comment: Is that for Excel?

Comment: You could do for instance `=SUMIF(B1:B9, "<>"&MAX(B1:B9))/COUNTIF(B1:B9, "<>"&MAX(B1:B9))`, ie calculate the average the old fashioned way by summing up all desired values and dividing by the count

Comment: Hi Jason!
Maybe I forgot to told that I’m working in Google Sheets.
I manage to get your formulas working -it was not exactly what I was searching for! 
BUT! 
You solution was a great deal of inspiration!

The following Function did the trick!

=AVERAGEIF(B23:B37,”<>”&MAX(B23:B37))

Thanks !